# AngularJS directive not getting value from service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In a nutshell, I'm using an AngularJS service in both a directive and a controller. When a change to a service value is performed in the controller that value does not update in the directive. What am I missing here?

I tried adding a watch on the directive's scope.value but it's not actually changing.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])
  .directive('myDirective', function (myService) {
    return {
      controller: function ($scope, myService) {
        angular.extend($scope, myService);
      },
      scope: {},
      template: 'Directive: <select ng-model="absValue" ng-options="r for r in absRange()"></select> {{absValue}}'
    };
  })
  .service('myService', function () {
    return {
      absRange: function () {
        var value = this.value;

        return range(2 * this.value + 1).map(function (r) { return r - (value + 1); });
      },
      absValue: 0,
      value: 3
    };
  });

function myController($scope, myService) {
  this.range = range(5);

  angular.extend(this, myService);
}
```

Here's the plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/oAlzJ5gNQ4uXaJV2Bh9z?p=preview

Comment: A few notes. 1) you have not injected your controller anywhere. 2) you do not need a service for what you are doing here, and extending scope with the service is not what you want to do. You should be adding stuff to your controller, and then passing it into the scope of your directive with scope: {range: "="}. 3)

Comment: Why everybody is doing some horrible things with angular? The base is to isolate every part of the code, then, separate ;-) My updated plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/s1RinJJBNzqNXXCyPrb8?p=preview